# Windows 8 text is on the right side of desktop icon

Tags: windows-8

I accidentally pressed some keys and the text is aligned on the right side of desktop each icon. Here is a snapshot. I have spent 2 hours but could not find a solution. I would really appreciate if anyone can help!!

[image]

Comment: What language packs do you have installed?  This behavior was caused by third-party software.

Answer (score -1):

The only source I found is by using [**D-Color**](http://Display%20Desktop%20icons%20text%20on%20the%20side%20in%20Windows%207%20with%20D-Color)

> D-Color is a free portable app that lets you customize and change the
> appearance of your desktop icons, its text foreground and background
> colors and also allows you to change the view of your desktop icons
> from Large, Small and Tile view icons.

P.S. - *Worked fine on Windows 7 x64, but it is always a good idea to create a system restore point first before trying out any new software. Looks like it works on Windows 8 too!*

Comment: Please Comment on Down-votes so that Answer can be improved :)

Comment: Is this a cause of the problem or a solution? This *isn't* regular functionality on windows so... suggesting even more software may not be a good answer. Also, copy-pasting descriptions makes it look like an ad or a softwarr rec. A good answer would go through what's causing this and then how to fix it